# How To select Particular Cell Value in Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to select Particular Cell value and will use to Bind Controls But i am Not able to select Cell Value
Its not retrieving data

[image]

ASPX Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdLogedUserDetails" OnRowDeleting="grdLogedUserDetails_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="grdLogedUserDetails_RowDataBound"
                runat="server" Style="width: 100%; text-align: center" OnRowCommand="grdLogedUserDetails_RowCommand"
                class="table table-striped table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false" datakeynames="Ref_ID">
                <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Process No">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ref_ID") %>' ID="lblRef_ID"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>' ID="lblCompanyName"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DivisionName") %>' ID="lblDivisionName"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" AlternateText="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
      </ItemTemplate>
     <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
                        
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-icon.png" AlternateText="Select" CommandName="Select" />
     </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

C#

```
protected void grdLogedUserDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            //Reference the GridView Row.
            GridViewRow row = grdLogedUserDetails.Rows[rowIndex];

            //Access Cell values.
            int RefID= int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);
            string Company= row.Cells[1].Text;
            string Division= row.Cells[2].Text;
        }
protected void grdLogedUserDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Access Cell values.
        var RefId = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);  // Error Input string is not in correct Formate
        string Comany= e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
        string Division= e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
    }
}
```

While Debugging I can see Error Like :

"Input string is not in correct Format" Where i am doing wrong

My Table Structure

```
________________________________________
Ref_ID|  CompanyName  |  DivisionName   |
______|_______________|_________________|
6     |   Company     |    Sales        |
8     |   Company     |    Sales        |
14    |   Company     |    Sales        |
______|_______________|_________________|
```

**RefID** i have taken as "int" and **CompanyName**   and **DivisionName**   "string" so where i my input string is in wrong format,

Where i am doing wrong Please suggest me on same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rowcommand event does not trigger rowindexed change unless you have Command="Select" but you DO HAVE Command="Select". However, you don't have a CommandArugment.

However, since you do have command=Select, then move your code to SelectedIndexChanged. The issue is you can't get/grab the row from the "row" command event since the row has not changed. The rowcommand event fires before SelectedIndexChanged. And as noted, unless you use a special command (delete or select) then SelectedIndexChanged does NOT fire.

So rowindex will NOT have been set in the row command event.  However, this will mean that for your select button (and delete) your code will be (can be) in rowindexchanged "if" you use say select (or "delete") for the command. if you use a custom command name, then rowindexedchanged does NOT fire.

You can continue to use rowcommand, but you need the CommandArugment to pass either the PK of the row, or the index of the row.

So you have two choices here. (actually 3).

You can set the value of CommandArugment of that button.
Either to the PK, or you can use this

```
CommandArgument ='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'
```

I note that in your command settings, you are NOT setting the CommandArugment - you have to set it in your markup. The above expression will return the index into the grid.

You can move your code to rowindexchanged.

However, there is a 3rd choice. You CAN GET the rowindex in rowcommand. So from the depths of hell, you can use this stunning whopper insane of a statement:

```
If e.CommandName = "MySelect" Then
        ' now get row.
        Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

        Debug.Print("row index = " & gvRow.DataItemIndex)

        Dim MyLabel As Label = gvRow.FindControl("HotelName")
        Debug.Print("Value ref id = " & MyLabel.Text)

    End If
```

Note VERY careful:
For the templated fields - we use find control. For non tempalted fields, then you can reference by cell.

Now that super award winning ugly way to get the row in row command?

In C# it will look like this:

```
{
  GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(Control)e.CommandSource.NamingContainer;
}
```

So, you have to use above, or as noted, move your code to SelectedIndexChanged.

Since you only have a select and delete button, then I would suggest SelectedIndexChanged. But if you were to say introduce another button - then you would not want to use Select or Delete, but a custom command name of your choosing (say CommandName="MyViewer"). In that case, then SelectedIndexChanged will not fire. But then you would have a means to determine which button was clicked upon (beyond the need of select and delete commands).

```
So in summary:
You have about 3+ ways to do this.
Keep in mind that in row command, the selected index event has NOT yet fired.
Keep in mind that if you use a custom row command name, then selected index WILL NOT fire.
Keep in mind that you can pick up the selected row with that award winning ugly line of code.
Keep in mind that you can't use cells() collection for your custom templated columns - so use find control. 
Keep in mind that selectedindex in row command event has NOT changed nor fired yet.
```

Since you ARE using select, then you have a choice of row command event, or selectedindex changed event - they will both fire in your case.

Comment: Thanks For such a nice explanation and thank you so much for your concern and time thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cell does not contain any text, but a Label `lblRef_ID`. So you need to access the label, not the cell value.

```
var label = e.Row.FindControl("lblRef_ID") as Label;
var RefId = int.Parse(label.Text);
```

Comment: I am getting Error on Row and Label

Comment: You can use/get e.row in selected index changed, but NOT in row command. So as noted, move your code, or use that super ugly statement - you can then use find control once you used Mr. Ugly statement to get the row.